[SM-S916W]How to removal/bypass FRP Lock?



Model
SM-S916W




CSC version
S916WOYV4CXI4


Firmware
https://samfw.com/firmware/SM-S916W/XAC|


FRP status
TRIGGERED


ADB status
Sideload


Wifi/SIM
connected/yes


Country
CA


Recovery
samsung/dm2qcsx/dm2q13/TP1A.220624.014/S916WVLS4CXI4user/release-keys


USB Debugging
Disabled


Bootloader
Locked



There is no option to unlock bootloader from the download mode and Reboot to bootloader from recovery mode does not work either.
Options I already tried:​

SamFw Tool 4.9:

Remove FRP (USA models 2024)
Remove FRP (security from August 2022 to December 2022)
Remove FRP (security older than August 2022)
MTP> KG Unlock (Untested): brought up AT Command but i couldn't understand and didn't go past that point
Download Mode> FRP Android 5/6 both method.
android > FRP > Remove FRP, Open Browser
android > FRP > App Manager > tried installing app-debug.apk


Odin 3.14:

Flashed latest stock firmware
tried flashing TWRP dm2q and vbmeta but failed.


Accessibility talk back and emergency call codes

talk back menu's only options:

read from next item
copy last spoken phrase
spoken language
screen search
hide screen
describe image


Emergency call codes are useless.



I haven't tried combination firmware option because I could not find the combination firmware for this model.
Please tell me what next steps should I take and what other information/logs should I provide?
Is there any ADB sideload exploits available that could work?
Is it even possible to remove/bypass FRP lock from newer models like S23 plus?
